# present simple vs. present perfect

Tags: tense, aspect

I am a little bit confused by this sentence:

> After annexing Crimea and with troops massed on the border of Ukraine, Vladimir Putin will not stop trying to expand Russia **until he has “conquered”** Belarus, the Baltic states and Finland, one of his closest former advisers has said.

I cannot understand why in the emphasized part of the sentence the present perfect is used. I would await the simple present in this type of the clause. The sentence suggests that Putin has already started the conquest of other countries, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

*Until* designates a point in the future; the present perfect (which you should keep in mind is a present-tense construction) defines that point as the point at which the conquest is a prior event giving rise to a current state: the completion of the conquest.

The sentence says nothing about when the conquest starts, only about when it is finished.

Comment: I wonder, would "until he conquers" be equivalent?

Comment: @CopperKettle In this case, with a telic verb, the present perfect and the simple present have pragmatically the same meaning; but this does not hold with verbs of other sorts.

Comment: @StoneyB What is a "telic" verb?

Comment: @Jasper A verb with a goal or completion 'built in' to its sense. See the [Aspect](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info) tag-wiki.